# sum of columns in database table returning 0

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using mySql database.

I created a method to calculate the sum of a column. It is working fine.

```
public int calculate(String department) {
    int sum = 0;
    try {
        BaseDao baseDao = new BaseDao();
        Connection connection = baseDao.getConnection();
        String query = "select sum(Allocation) from test.Employee where Department=?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, department);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int c=resultSet.getInt(1);
            sum = sum+c;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sum; 
}
```

I also created another method in which i am calculating sum of columns and also i mentioned a two conditions, but it is not working. It is showing the sum is 0.

```
    public int calculate2(String managerId, String managerId2) {
    int sum = 0;
    try {
        BaseDao baseDao = new BaseDao();
        Connection connection = baseDao.getConnection();
        String query = "select sum(Allocation) from test.Employee where EmployeeId=? and Manager=?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, managerId);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, managerId2);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int c = resultSet.getInt(1);
            sum=sum+c;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Here is the error log

```
Oct 03, 2013 9:06:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/SavvisProject] has started
Oct 03, 2013 9:06:22 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/SavvisProject] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Oct 03, 2013 9:06:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/SavvisProject] is completed
```

Comment: Have you tried entering the query you try to run directly into mySql? Maybe the sum actually is 0.

Comment: Are you sure there's data in the database for the values you're testing with for EmployeeID and Manager. Also, assuming EmployeeID is the primary key of the Employee table, why do you need to also filter on manager (and if there's only one row with any given EmployeeID, why would you need to aggregate the result)?

Comment: I am sorry, actually i want the result for condition where EmployeeId=? or Manager=? now, i got my answer.

Comment: @spydon you are correct. The result of that query is 0.